# How to read a single value from a tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver from sync code?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to receive a stream of bytes from async code into sync code.

The `MultiBuf` type contains a `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver` and a thread (not shown here) sends `Bytes` objects to it. In my sync code, I want to call `next_chunk` to receive bytes from the Receiver, but only when the caller is ready to consume these bytes.

The difficulty is that calling `rx.blocking_recv()` requires the calling thread to own the Receiver.

```rust
    pub struct MultiBuf {
        recv: Receiver<Bytes>,
        curr_chunk: Bytes,
    }
    
    pub fn new_multibuf(recv: Receiver<Bytes>) -> MultiBuf {
        MultiBuf {
            recv,
            curr_chunk: Bytes::new(),
        }
    }
    
    pub fn next_chunk(buf: &mut MultiBuf) -> &[u8] {
        let next = {
            let mut rx = buf.recv.clone();
            let sync_call = std::thread::spawn(move || rx.blocking_recv());
            sync_call.join().unwrap()
        };
        match next {
            Some(v) => {
                buf.curr_chunk = v;
                &buf.curr_chunk[..]
            }
            None => &[],
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that `buf.recv` cannot be cloned, and we cannot give ownership of the `Receiver` to the spawned thread, because it needs to be called repeatedly.

I realize this may not be the right way to do this, but what would a better way be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
let sync_call = std::thread::spawn(move || rx.blocking_recv());
sync_call.join().unwrap()
```

This thread does nothing useful; by calling `join()` immediately, you're blocking on the thread's completion, and the thread is blocking on `blocking_recv()`, so the current thread is indirectly blocking on `blocking_recv()`. You might as well do it directly:

```rust
let next = buf.recv.blocking_recv();
```

That will have the same effect as your code would have, but without the ownership problem you're asking about.